# Can someone explain these F# type inference oddities?

Tags: f#, type-inference

I'm experiencing a lot of unexplained behavior with the type inference of F# (or lack of inference rather).

I would expect that all the `value` functions below would return the correct type `T` given a `Foo of T` but in several cases it returns an `obj`.

```
type Foo<'T>(v:'T) =
    member __.Value = v // 'T
    static member (~~) (foo:Foo<_>) = foo.Value // Foo<'a> -> 'a

// should know the type but not always!
~~(Foo 1)                                       // int
let value (u:Foo<_>) = u.Value                  // Foo<'a> -> 'a
let value (u:Foo<_>) = ~~u                      // Foo<obj> -> obj
let inline value (u:Foo<_>) = ~~u               // Foo< ^a> -> ^a

let (~~) (foo:Foo<_>) = (Foo<_>.(~~))foo        // Foo<'a> -> 'a
let value (u:Foo<_>) = ~~u                      // Foo<'a> -> 'a

let inline (~~) (x:^a) : ^b = 
    (^a : (static member (~~) : ^a -> ^b) x)    // ^a -> ^b
let value (u:Foo<_>) = ~~u                      // Foo<obj> -> obj

let inline (~~) (x:^a) : 'b = 
    (^a : (static member (~~) : ^a -> 'b) x)    // ^a -> 'b
let value (u:Foo<_>) = ~~u                      // Foo<'a> -> 'a
```

What is going on??

Comment: What exactly is your question? I copy pasted your code into F# editor and it all looks fine (aside from the fact that it is redefining values of the same name, which is not allowed).

Comment: I would have thought that the correct type is inferred but as you see from the signatures sometimes obj is returned

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Makes sense now! Could you maybe say this more explicitly in your question, just to make sure it does not get closed?

Comment: Indeed, inference of `let value (u:Foo<_>) = ~~u`  is loosing generic type. But why using `~~` operator instead of `Value` member (for which inference works)? Did you want to hide `Value` (making it `private`) to only access it with `~~` ?

Comment: @RomainDeneau no I want to save precious finger movements, but ultimately I want to understand what is going on behind the scenes.

Comment: As this behavior really seems strange and as not even Tomas seems to know what is going on (or maybe he forgot that one) I'd suggest opening an issue with this on the compiler repo - IMO you'll either get an explanation or it might get fixed somewhere along the way

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell why certain functions involving an invocation of your `op_TwiddleTwiddle` operator definitions cannot be generalized. On the other hand, there are definitively interesting things happening here. Let's start by bringing the code into a form that avoid redefinitions of top-level bindings:

```
type Foo<'T>(v:'T) =
    member __.Value = v // 'T
    static member (~~) (foo:Foo<_>) = foo.Value     // Foo<'a> -> 'a

module M1 =
    let value (u:Foo<_>) = ~~u                      // Foo<obj> -> obj

module M2 =
    let inline value (u:Foo<_>) = ~~u               // Foo< ^a> -> ^a

module M3 =
    let (~~) (foo:Foo<_>) = (Foo<_>.(~~))foo        // Foo<'a> -> 'a
    let value (u:Foo<_>) = ~~u                      // Foo<'a> -> 'a

module M4 =
    let inline (~~) (x:^a) : ^b = 
        (^a : (static member (~~) : ^a -> ^b) x)    // ^a -> ^b
    let value (u:Foo<_>) = ~~u                      // Foo<obj> -> obj

module M5 =
    let inline (~~) (x:^a) : 'b = 
        (^a : (static member (~~) : ^a -> 'b) x)    // ^a -> 'b
    let value (u:Foo<_>) = ~~u                      // Foo<'a> -> 'a
```

Looking at the compiled form of the `Foo<'T>` type, it is clear that the operator takes a type parameter for its return type:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    internal T v;

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.v;
        }
    }

    public Foo(T v) : this()
    {
        this.v = v;
    }

    public static a op_TwiddleTwiddle<a>(Foo<a> foo)
    {
        return foo.v;
    }
}
```

This is immaterial as none of the examples except the `M2` inline definition do actually call the `op_TwiddleTwiddle` operator. All the other examples are optimized by direct access to the backing field of the `Value` property, albeit we would expect it to be transparent, not influencing generalization.

The other interesting cases are

- `M3`, where annotation of the operator `Foo<_>.(~~)` improves the generalization, and
- `M5`, in that elimination of the second (unnecessary) statically resolved type variable also makes it work better.